# How to update the repository locally through command line

Tags: git, command-line, bitbucket, git-clone

I have cloned the repository locally using the command,"git clone repository-url"
to my local machine.Now suppose if there is any changes in the repository,How do I update it in local machine.Is there any command to do it?
another command 'git status' gives me the info of the repository is updated or not.but how do i update my local repository folder with the new change.
Cloning again is not possible.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `git pull` is what you need

Comment: "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"This is the error I have getting on 'git pull'

Comment: In the same directory where you can execute `git status`? Is there a `.git` folder?

Comment: Please use it inside the directory created by the clone.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate as the other question assumes that the user already knows that everything must be in the correct folder...

Answer (score 1):

To answer your basic question: You need to execute `git pull` inside the folder created by the `git clone`.

Example for clone:

```
git clone https://gitserver/repository.git
```

This creates a folder named `repository`.

To update you have to change into the folder created and issue a `git pull`:

```
cd repository
git pull
```